# removing the full stop after "excercise"

Tags: numbering, punctuation

So I am doing a homework assignment. The homework is selected numbers from various pages of the textbook. So I can not use a ordered list, ie. 1, 2, 3, ...

So I was looking at some ways to separate and give my solutions a heading. The best I could find was

```
\begin{xca}
\textbf {24 Page 45}
    ...
\end{xca}
```

but that dosn't look very good since it puts a period after "excercise". I have attached a picture.

I am either looking to get rid of the fullstop, or some alternate way. It would be best that if I create a pdf (and a table of contents) to go along with it, it should have the title as a clickable link. But if thats too complicated, help me remove the fullstop.

I am using Lyx.

Thanks
[image]

Comment: Where do you want the title to point to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how the `xca` environment is defined (maybe you could add the relevant bit from the preamble), but maybe

```
\begin{xca}[24 Page 45]
    ...
\end{xca}
```

displays nicely.

If it is just solutions to exercises, you could also do `\section*{Exercise 24, Page 45}` instead of the environment (or `\subsection`). This is what I usually do when typesetting solutions to assignments.